# Google Apps Script map tutorial error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am having a problem with the maps tutorial specified here, https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/maps_tutorial

I am trying to do the first tutorial, make a map from a list of addresses.

I have created the spreadsheet and script, but I get this error when I run the script.

"Cannot find method getRange(number,number,number,number). (line 7)"

Any tips/solutions?

Comment: Do you have a sheet called 'restaurants' ? Also, it is populated with data ?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the second line it should be something like:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('restaurants');
```

Basically the script expects to have a sheet inside the spreadsheet file called "restaurants" so try to rename the sheet and it should not fail.